# IOS, UITabelView not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableView added to a UIView, when the data comes back from the database I'm passing the data into an NSMutableArray. When the cells get rendered i create UIViews inside the cell with the data outputted into this UIView. Now the Cells get rendered with the UIViews and i can see that the UIViews are showing. But the scrollbar is not working as i cannot scroll down to see the other Cells that contain the UIViews with data.

Code:

```
        tableViewThreads = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 104, screenRect.size.width, 336)];
        tableViewThreads.delegate = self;
        tableViewThreads.dataSource = self;
        tableViewThreads.bounces = YES;
        tableViewThreads.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        [viewTopThread addSubview:tableViewThreads];

        tableViewThreads.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tableViewThreads];



        -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            if(tableViewThreads == tableView){
            return [threadsArray count];
            }

            return 0;
        }

        -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }
            if(tableViewThreads == tableView){
            ThreadInfo *threadInfo = (ThreadInfo*)[self.threadsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self setupThreadItem:threadInfo]];

            //[cell.textLabel setText:tweet];
            //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"via Codigator"];
            }

            return cell;
        }

        - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            if(tableViewThreads == tableView){

            return 122;

            }

            return 0;
        }


-(void)renderThreadInfo:(NSDictionary*)dic{

                NSDictionary *thread = [dic objectForKey:@"thread"];

                int t_ID;
                int t_U_ID;
                int t_C_ID;
                NSString *t_Name;
                NSString *t_Description;
                NSDate *t_Created;
                int t_Flagged;
                int t_Rated;

                for(NSDictionary *dict in thread)
                {
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_ID"] intValue];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_U_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_U_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_U_ID"] intValue];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_C_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_C_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_C_ID"] intValue];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Name"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Name = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Name"];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Description"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Description = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Description"];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"] != [NSNull null]){
                    NSString *timestampString = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"];
                    double timestampDate = [timestampString doubleValue];
                    t_Created = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampDate];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Flagged"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Flagged = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_Flagged"] intValue];
                }
                if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Rated"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Rated = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_Rated"] intValue];
                }

                ThreadInfo *threadObj = [ThreadInfo new];
                threadObj.iD = t_ID;
                threadObj.userId  = t_U_ID;
                threadObj.catId = t_C_ID;
                threadObj.name = t_Name;
                threadObj.description = t_Description;
                threadObj.timeStampCreated = t_Created;
                threadObj.flagged = t_Flagged;
                threadObj.rated = t_Rated;

                [threadsArray addObject:threadObj];

                [tableViewThreads reloadData];

                }

            }
```

Comment: Hint: I'm betting you have auto-layout turned on...

Comment: @Stonz2, auto-layout?

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the UITableView to the wrong UIView.

Should be:

```
[self.viewCreateThread addSubview:tableViewThreads];
```

But when i now scroll the app crashes, i will open another question.

Thanks